# Converting a raw Ec key to DER encoded

Tags: openssl, cryptography, elliptic-curve

I have a EC 192 bit key which is in raw format for ex:
UHWo9mjrEqDeng4wWTtEgpAUJnvoMzD0ZLMA8Rd777o=

however in order to import this to an HSM i have to convert it to DER-encoded key.
Is there a way i can achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Public key or private key? DER encoding of which format?

Comment: That example shows 32 bytes. That seems strange for a 192 bit EC key. It would be relatively easy if you have an ASN.1 encoder library. Of course, that means programming, not using the command line interface. OTOH, this **is** [so].

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk sorry i should have mentioned, its a EC private key

Comment: @MaartenBodewes its 24 bytes, two chars representing a single byte, so we do not have a regular way i can use apart from programming, like using openssl or any other utility?

Comment: Nope, I agree with @MaartenBodewes, it's 32 bytes *after* it is base64 decoded. That would suggest it is a private key for one of the 256-bit curves.

Comment: I must be wrong here then, apologies. How would i convert it to base64 encoded?